# Forms and routing in Spartacus

Tags: angular, forms, routes, display, spartacus-storefront

In spartacus page I need to create one form which takes firstName, lastName and Description and has submit button. After giving input clicking on submit it should route to different link and show the output. How to do it??

I tried but I am only able to display it on that same page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.